# How do I make a web blog that takes posts from seperate txt files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to make a blog on my own website without using a service like Wordpress, Joomla, etc that takes content from text files in a seperate directory and displays them on the webpage. This is what I have so far:

## HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>doggo.info</title>

    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://doggo.info/stylesheet.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://doggo.info/navbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <img src="/images/navicon.png" onclick="openNav()" width="40" height="48" alt="Open Menu">
  <a href="/" title="Home Page"><em>doggo.info</em></a>
</header>
<div id="sidenav">
  <a id="current">curlink</a>
  <a href="">otherlink</a>
</div>

<div id="load" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="textbox">
      <p id="posttitle"></p>
      <p id="postdate"></p>
      <p id="postcontent"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <p class="footer"><a href="/">doggo.info</a></p>
</footer>
</body>

<script>
$('#load').load("posts/post0.txt");
$('#posttitle').html($('#load').find('#title').html());
$('#postdate').html($('#load').find('#date').html());
$('#postcontent').html($('#load').find('#content').html());
</script>

</html>
```

## 0.TXT

```
<div id="title">Title of post</div>
<div id="date">1/1/1990</div>
<div id="content">
hi, i am blog.
<br>
<em>indeed</em>, it is true
<br>
what is <strong>life</strong>?
</div>
```

If there's a better way to formatting my txt files, I'm open to changing them.

I want to be able to have multiple files in the posts folder and have the site load them in decending order (99.txt, 98.txt, 97.txt ... 0.txt) into the page inside of textbox divs. I would also like it into pages with 10 or so posts a page.

I'm pretty much stumped, so any help would be appreciated. You can view what I've gotten so far [here](http://doggo.info/blog).

Comment: Yes, please switch to `.json` or `.xml`. These are easy to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSONs and AJAX to access the information that u want to display.

JavaScriptObjectNotation or JSON is a way you can format your files and access information that you want.

[

```
  {

  "Title": "Title of post",

  "Date" : "1/1/1990",

  "Content": "h, i am blog"
  }
```

]

The file is saved as a ".json" and its contents are organised as objects.

This video is very helpful if you are new to JSON

[JSON and AJAX YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw&t=5s)